# Stopping a Job in the beforeStep in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want to be able to stop a job when a timing threshold is met. There are 2 approaches I was thinking about. First was to stop the job in the afterStep. However, I do not want it to have a Stopped status if it is at the completion of the last step. Therefore, I am going with stopping it in the beforeStep.
I tried experimenting with

```
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    stepExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPED);
    return;
}
```

and

```
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    stepExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.STOPPED);
    return;
}
```

Neither of these worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

See this question right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023018/how-to-halt-a-spring-batch-job-from-a-stepexecutionlistener-afterstep-method?rq=1), the OP has the solution to this in his question.

The `jobListener` is a little bit different

```
@Override
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();
        
        //check params etc
        
        if (!shouldExecute) {
            jobExecution.stop();
            jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("STOPPED", "Invalid state."));
            return;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above code is that stops the currently running step, not the entire job.
 Perhaps if you add and adjust the following code in the job-current-step configuration will terminate the job when the ExitStatus of the step is STOPPED and when runned again the job will start from the next step.
(Taken from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#configuringForStop))

```
<step id="step1" parent="s1">
    <stop on="STOPPED" restart="step2"/>
</step>
```

[This](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#batchStatusVsExitStatus) might also help solve the confusion between ExitStatus/BatchStatus.

About the  timing threshold... As I understand so far you plan to measure time of the **current step only** (beforestep - afterstep), no matter how long previous steps were running. To calculate and the previous steps try adding a timestamp in JobParameters and check when that threshold is passed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case a needed to stop job from afterStep. So I returned ExitStatus.Unknown and catch from job like that:

step().on("UNKNOWN").end()

So the job finish without error and I can restart the entire job when i want, whitout "restartable" option.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest looking at [CompletionPolicies](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/repeat.html#completionPolicies) especially the [TimeoutTerminationPolicy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/repeat/policy/TimeoutTerminationPolicy.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timer (or something similar) and when receive time-limit notitication stop the job as described in [Stopping a job](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#stoppingAJob).
If you want the job is completed normally even if a time-alarm were broadcasted during last step, you can do check (using [`JobOperator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#JobOperator)) to query job progress.