# Spring batch stop a job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How can I stop a job in spring batch ? I tried to use this method using the code below:

```
public class jobListener implements JobExecutionListener{

  @Override
  public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    jobExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.STOPPED);

  }


  @Override
  public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
}
```

I tried also COMPLETED,FAILED but this method doesn't work and the job continues to execute. Any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping a Job in the beforeStep in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122059/stopping-a-job-in-the-beforestep-in-spring-batch)

Answer (score 5):

You can use JobOperator along with JobExplorer to stop a job from outside the job (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#JobOperator).  The method is `stop(long executionId)`  You would have to use JobExplorer to find the correct executionId to stop.

Also from within a job flow config you can configure a job to stop after a steps execution based on exit status (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#stopElement).

Comment: will it kill the process or just mark the job execution STOPPED

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to stop a job by a given name. 
Here is the code.

```
String jobName = jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName(); // in most cases
DataSource dataSource = ... //@Autowire it in your code
JobOperator jobOperator = ... //@Autowire it in your code
JobExplorerFactoryBean factory = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
factory.setJdbcOperations(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
JobExplorer jobExplorer = factory.getObject();
Set<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
jobExecutions.forEach(jobExecution -> jobOperator.stop(jobExecution.getId()));
```

Comment: It just marks stopped but executes full job